Why does plain TeX test if the \topins box is void before unboxing it?
According to Chapter 23 of the TeXbook, \pagecontents is defined as:
\ifvoid\topins \else\unvbox\topins\fi
\dimen0=\dp255 \unvbox255
\ifvoid\footins\else % footnote info is present
  \vskip\skip\footins
  \footnoterule
  \unvbox\footins\fi
\ifraggedbottom \kern-\dimen0 \vfil \fi

Is there any reason why \ifvoid\topins \else\unvbox\topins\fi can't simply be \unvbox\topins?
According to the TeXbook, you can \unvbox a void vbox, and the result is that nothing happens. Chapter 15 says:

… if \box3 is void, you can say \unhbox3 or \unvbox3 or \unhcopy3 or \unvcopy3 …

And Chapter 24 says:

\unvbox<8-bit number>, \unvcopy<8-bit number>. If the specified box register is void, nothing happens. …


it's not necessarily true that nothing happens, is it? if you are not currently in vertical mode, there is a difference because \unvbox will leave the current mode and enter vertical mode, won't it? so \newbox\mybox xxx\unvbox\mybox yyy\par\bye is different from \newbox\mybox xxx\relax yyy\par\bye. but presumably you should be in vertical mode already, so it wouldn't matter?

You are right, \unvbox\topins does nothing here if \topins is void because \pagecontents is opened in vertical mode.
We cannot know exactly what Knuth had in mind. Maybe, he used the same test as in \ifvoid\footins because of some symmetry and because plain TeX is starting format. Or he overlooked it. Maybe there was more activities when \topins was non-empty in previous versions of the \pagecontents macro.

I mean you can, at least in theory, ask him. I just wanted to emphasise that he is very much alive.
